# How do I interact with the console during boot time on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an instance which is stuck at this boot prompt (looking at the instance log from the management console):

```
The disk drive for /mydisk is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I added an EBS volume, mounted it, then deleted the EBS volume and forgot to remove the entry from /etc/fstab and rebooted the machine. Now it prompts me that at boot time, and I am unable to SSH into the instance.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know an 'easy' solution to your problem, but there is a somewhat convoluted (depending on your root device type) solution.

If your instance has an EBS root, the solution is simple enough: stop the instance, detach the EBS drive, launch another instance and attach the EBS volume to it. Edit your fstab file as needed, detach the EBS volume and re-attach it to the original instance.

If your instance has an S3-backed root (i.e. instance-store), the solution is a good bit harder. You can download the data from your AMI (using [ec2-download-bundle](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-download-bundle.html)), and then extract that data into a single file (using [ec2-unbundle](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-unbundle.html)). You can then mount the image, make the necessary change, and rebundle the image (with [ec2-bundle-vol](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-bundle-vol.html), overriding the default volume to bundle with the -v flag). That should give you a new, viable AMI, identical to your old one, except for the modifications you make. Alternatively, you could copy the content of the image file to an EBS volume using dd - and then convert to an EBS root backed instance.

Comment: Thankfully, my instance has an EBS root! Thanks a lot for the answer. I will try it out and confirm that it works.

Comment: ErJab: I wrote an article describing how to do this with EBS boot: http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root

Comment: Would it be prudent to also add `nofail` to `/etc/fstab` in case you make a typo? Maybe not, maybe "errors" (as described in `fstab(5)`) don't hold up the boot process.

Comment: @AdamMonsen: that is good practice for some drives - e.g. ephemeral drives, since the boot process will exit to recovery mode if a disk is unavailable. I usually use the option `nobootwait` - haven't tried with `nofail` - I believe there are some subtle differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

If your ubuntu has `systemd`, you can edit `/lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target` and comment out the last two lines:

```
#OnFailure=emergency.target
#OnFailureJobMode=replace-irreversibly
```

I haven't tested this extensively and don't know if there are any risks or side effects involved, but so far it works like a charm. It mounts the root volume and all other volumes (except those that are misconfigured, obviously), then it continues the boot process until SSH is up, so you can connect to the instance and fix the incorrect `fstab` entries.